# Android: AbsListView.setItemChecked() cause ActionMode Destroy and Recreate?

Tags: android, actionmode

If you call `AbsListView.setItemChecked()` directly, it works well, and the `ActionMode` will activate and create.

```
mGridView.setItemChecked(pPosition, true);
```

But when you call `View.startActionMode()` first, then call `AbsListView.setItemChecked()`, the `ActionMode` create by `startActionMode()` will destroy, and recreate a new one by `setItemChecked()`.

My question is: How to avoid this issue when call `View.startActionMode()` first?

Looking forward to your reply! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why recreate a new one? See the source code of `AbsListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean value)` method, you can see following code：

```
    // Start selection mode if needed. We don't need to if we're unchecking something.
    if (value && mChoiceMode == CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL && mChoiceActionMode == null) {
        if (mMultiChoiceModeCallback == null ||
                !mMultiChoiceModeCallback.hasWrappedCallback()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("AbsListView: attempted to start selection mode " +
                    "for CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL but no choice mode callback was " +
                    "supplied. Call setMultiChoiceModeListener to set a callback.");
        }
        mChoiceActionMode = startActionMode(mMultiChoiceModeCallback);
    }
```

That means if `mChoiceActionMode == null`, it will call `startActionMode(mMultiChoiceModeCallback)`, so will recreate a new ActionMode.

And how to fix?
Here is a simple way: use reflect to assign a ActionMode create by `startActionMode()` to the private field `mChoiceActionMode` in `AbsListView`.

```
private void startActionMode() {
    // Get the field "mMultiChoiceModeCallback" instance by reflect
    AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener wrapperIns = null;
    try {
        Field wrapper = null;
        wrapper = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mMultiChoiceModeCallback");
        wrapper.setAccessible(true);
        wrapperIns = (AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener) wrapper.get(mMessageGridView);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Start the ActionMode, but not select any item. 
    ActionMode actionMode = mMessageGridView.startActionMode(wrapperIns);
    // Assign actionMode to field "mChoiceActionMode" by reflect 
    try {
        Field mChoiceActionMode = null;
        mChoiceActionMode = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mChoiceActionMode");
        mChoiceActionMode.setAccessible(true);
        mChoiceActionMode.set(mMessageGridView, actionMode);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Why here we use wrapper? Because `AbsListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(MultiChoiceModeListener listener)` will wrap our mMultiChoiceModeListener, so we can't not use directly.